# Docusign API - Inserting new pages on documents created using templates

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create envelope using templates. I have a unique use case where I would need to repeat one of the pages on the template based on the user input upfront before generating the docusign envelope to sign.

My template-1 has 12 pages with sign tab on 12th page. Based on user input I might have to include multiple page#4 and multiple pag#10 in between at the time of envelope creation. So my final docusign document for signature will be having pages 1,2,...4, 4a, 4b, 5, ........9, 10, 10a, 10b, 1oc, 11,12.

One suggestion I got was to use composite templates and have the pages added on the fly. But my question is, then wouldn't that require my template-1 to be broken down into multiple templates based off where new pages need to be inserted? Is there any other way I can achieve this, as I might end up having quite a bunch of split templates out of a single template.

Comment: To give more clarity, currently these forms are done manually, so user takes multiple copies of required pages (here #4, #10) and fill values and insert it in between other pages before final signature is done. We are trying to replace it with online signature.

Comment: Any suggestions on this use case?